# Having trouble understanding where I am going wrong with my hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the following error message when I log in to the frontend of an app I'm building and I'm having trouble understanding why but I've narrowed it down to three files. I understand that I am rendering the LoginForm or BlogForm components conditionally in App.js but I don't have any hooks in the files for those.

Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by App. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

### Previous render            Next render

1. useContext                 useContext
2. useRef                     useRef
3. useContext                 useContext
4. useRef                     useRef
5. useMemo                    useMemo
6. useSyncExternalStore       useSyncExternalStore
7. useEffect                  useEffect
8. useDebugValue              useDebugValue
9. useDebugValue              useDebugValue
10. useContext                useContext
11. useRef                    useRef
12. useMemo                   useMemo
13. useSyncExternalStore      useSyncExternalStore
14. useEffect                 useEffect
15. useDebugValue             useDebugValue
16. useDebugValue             useDebugValue
17. useState                  useState
18. useState                  useState
19. useState                  useState
20. useState                  useState
21. useState                  useState
22. useEffect                 useEffect
23. useEffect                 useEffect
24. undefined                 useContext
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

App@http://localhost:3000/main.36ead3e7b4f8451b2478.hot-update.js:49:76
Provider@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39885:7 bundle.js:14079:34

App.js

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import Blog from './components/Blog'
import blogService from './services/blogs'
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm'
import BlogForm from './components/BlogForm'
import Notification from './components/Notification'
import Togglable from './components/Togglable'
import { showNotification } from './reducers/notificationReducer'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { createBlog, initializeBlogs, likeBlog, deleteBlog } from './reducers/blogReducer'
import { setUser } from './reducers/userReducer'
import { useField } from './hooks'

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const blogFormRef = useRef()

  const blogs = useSelector(({ blogs }) => blogs)
  const user = useSelector(({ user }) => user)
  const username = useField('text')
  const password = useField('password')
  const title = useField('text')
  const author = useField('text')
  const url = useField('text')

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(initializeBlogs())
  }, [dispatch])

  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedBloglistappUser')
    if (loggedUserJSON !== 'null') {
      // console.log('loggedUserJSON: ' + loggedUserJSON)
      const user = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON)
      dispatch(setUser(user))
      blogService.setToken(user.token)
    }
  }, [])

  const addBlog = (blogObject) => {
    blogFormRef.current.toggleVisibility()
    dispatch(createBlog(blogObject))
    dispatch(showNotification(`a new blog ${blogObject.title} by ${blogObject.author}`, 5))
  }

  const deletePerson = (id, title, author) => {
    if(window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this blog?')) {
      dispatch(deleteBlog(id))
      dispatch(showNotification(`${title} by ${author} has been deleted from the bloglist`, 5))
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {user === null ?
        <div>
          <h2>log in to application</h2>
          <Notification />
          <LoginForm dispatch={dispatch} username={username} password={password} user={user}/>
        </div>
        :
        <div>
          <h2>blogs</h2>
          <Notification />
          <p>{user.name} logged in <button onClick={() => {
            window.localStorage.removeItem('loggedBloglistappUser')
            dispatch(showNotification('Logged out successfully. Reload the page to log in again.', 5))
          }
          }>Log out</button></p>
          <Togglable buttonLabel="create new blog" ref={blogFormRef}>
            <BlogForm createBlog={addBlog} title={title} author={author} url={url}/>
          </Togglable>
          {[...blogs].sort((a, b) => {
            return b.likes-a.likes
          }).map(blog =>
            <Blog key={blog.id} blog={blog} like={() => dispatch(likeBlog({ ...blog, user: blog.user.id, likes: blog.likes + 1 }))} deletePerson={typeof blog.user === 'string' || blog.user.username === useSelector(({ user }) => user).username ? () => deletePerson(blog.id, blog.title, blog.author) : null }/>
          )}
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

BlogForm.js

```
const BlogForm = ({ createBlog, title, author, url }) => {

  const addBlog = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    createBlog({
      title: title[0].value,
      author: author[0].value,
      url: url[0].value,
    })
    title[1]()
    author[1]()
    url[1]()
  }

  return (

    <form onSubmit={addBlog}>
      <h2>create new</h2>
      <div>
      title:
        <input {...title[0]} />
      </div>
      <div>
      author:
        <input {...author[0]}/>
      </div>
      <div>url:
        <input {...url[0]}/>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">create</button>
    </form>
  )
}
export default BlogForm
```

LoginForm.js

```
import { showNotification } from '../reducers/notificationReducer'
import { logIn } from '../reducers/userReducer'

const LoginForm = ({ dispatch, username, password, user }) => {

  const handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    try {
      dispatch(logIn({ username: username[0].value, password: password[0].value }))
      window.localStorage.setItem(
        'loggedBloglistappUser', JSON.stringify(user)
      )

      // blogService.setToken(user.token)
      username[1]()
      password[1]()
    } catch (exception) {
      console.log('exception: ', exception)
      dispatch(showNotification('Wrong username or password', 5))
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
      <div>
            username
        <input {...username[0]}/>
      </div>
      <div>
            password
        <input {...password[0]}/>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default LoginForm
```

hooks/index.js

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export const useField = (type) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value)
  }

  const reset = () => {
    setValue('')
  }

  return [{
    type,
    value,
    onChange,
  }, reset]
}
```

Comment: The error message seems to be about a conditional use of `useContext`, but your code samples don't include any uses of `useContext`. I expect the issue is likely with another file

Comment: @MarkHanna I don't have any uses of useContext in any other file either but I do have another file with a custom hook useField that I have edited my post to include

Comment: @cody53982., Is this issue occurring at which particular components visibility? Is it  LoginForm or BlogForm?

Comment: I am suspecting that inside the return function of App.js or just after the last useEffect of App.js (i.e., useEffect(() => {
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedBloglistappUser.......}) we are somehow making an extra useContext call without knowing.